# How can I get New Sender list over the years?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have two tables: 1. Sender 2. Dates

In sender tables, i have data about the sender like sender name, product type, sending date, arriving date, cost, and much more. In the sender table, data is for two years: 2020 and 2021.

In 2021, New Sender has come. This new sender is not sending any packages in 2020. So I want to create a new table that only consists of data about the new sender.

How can do it with DAX?
Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by CreatingNewTable from DAX; Something like:

```
NewSenders = 

var allSenders = VALUES('sender'[YourSenderID])
var SenderFromHistory = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES('sender'[YourSenderID]), 'sender'[Date] < DATEVALUE("2021-01-01"))
var OnlyNew = EXCEPT ( allSenders , SenderFromHistory )

return
CALCULATETABLE('sender', 'sender'[YourSenderID] in OnlyNew)
```

[image]